# for loop. can't hardcode the statement

Tags: javascript

```
function forfunction() {
    var arrNums = [4,15,10,7,6,23,1,18,8,45,-5,16,9,68];
    var output = "";
    output = "FOR RESULTS: ";
    var index = 0;
    for (index = 13; index < arrNums.length && index >= 0; index--) {
     output = output + arrNums[index] + " ";        
    }
    document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = output;
}
```

I was told I am not allowed to hardcode the statement, how to I go about changing the 'for' statement so I am not hardcoding?

Comment: `for (index < arrNums.length; index < arrNums.length && index > arrNums.length; index--)` --- it looks like you just put some random characters here.

Comment: The first piece of your for statement needs to be i=0, or omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looping logic is not correct :

Use below if you want to print numbers in sequence :

```
function forfunction() {
    var arrNums = [4,15,10,7,6,23,1,18,8,45,-5,16,9,68];
    var output = "";
    output = "FOR RESULTS: ";
    var index = 0;
    for (; index < arrNums.length; index++) {
     output = output + arrNums[index] + " ";        
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Use below if you want to print in reverse sequence :

```
function forfunction() {
    var arrNums = [4,15,10,7,6,23,1,18,8,45,-5,16,9,68];
    var output = "";
    output = "FOR RESULTS: ";
    var index = arrNums.length-1;
    for (; index >=0; index--) {
     output = output + arrNums[index] + " ";        
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: This is valid syntax, but non-standard use of `for()` to *not* have the index variable initialisation within the `for`. It would be more natural to say `for(var index = 0; index < arrNums.length; index++)`.